# Show total number of M365 licenses in Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, licensing

I wanted to create a Powershell script to show the total number and the assigned number of purchased M365 licenses. However, the output "ActiveUnits" doesn't exist in the cmdlet "Get-MgSubscribedSKU". Which output do I need to get the total number of purchased licenses?

Here is my code snippet:

```
Get-MgSubscribedSKU | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        License  = switch -Regex ($_.SkuPartNumber) {
            "VISIOCLIENT"                                           { "Visio Plan 2" }
        }
    Designation             = $_.SkuPartNumber
    LicenseID               = $_.SkuId
    NumberTotal             = $_.ActiveUnits
    NumberUsed              = $_.ConsumedUnits
    } 
} | sort License | Format-Table
```

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get the **total number** of purchased licenses, you need to modify your script to below:

```
Get-MgSubscribedSKU -All | Select-Object SkuPartNumber, SkuId, @{Name = "ActiveUnits"; Expression = { ($_.PrepaidUnits).Enabled } }, ConsumedUnits |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        License  = switch -Regex ($_.SkuPartNumber) {
            "VISIOCLIENT"                                           { "Visio Plan 2" }
        }
    Designation             = $_.SkuPartNumber
    LicenseID               = $_.SkuId
    NumberTotal             = $_.ActiveUnits
    NumberUsed              = $_.ConsumedUnits
    } 
} | sort License | Format-Table
```

In my Azure AD tenant, I have **licenses** with details like this:

[image]

When I ran below PowerShell script by making few changes, I got the **response** successfully like below:

```
Get-MgSubscribedSKU -All | Select-Object SkuPartNumber, SkuId, @{Name = "ActiveUnits"; Expression = { ($_.PrepaidUnits).Enabled } }, ConsumedUnits |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            License       = switch -Regex ($_.SkuPartNumber) {
                "EMSPREMIUM" { "Enterprise Mobility + Security E5" }
                "ENTERPRISEPREMIUM" { "Office 365 E5" }
                "ENTERPRISEPACK" { "Office 365 G3 GCC" }
                "DESKLESSPACK" { "Office 365 F3" }
                "FLOW_FREE" { "Microsoft Power Automate Free" }
                "Win10_VDA_E3" { "WINDOWS 10/11 ENTERPRISE E3" }
                "INFORMATION_PROTECTION_COMPLIANCE" { "Microsoft 365 E5 Compliance" }
            }
            Designation   = $_.SkuPartNumber
            LicenseID     = $_.SkuId
            NumberTotal   = $_.ActiveUnits
            NumberUsed    = $_.ConsumedUnits
        }
    } | Sort-Object License | Format-Table
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[How to get the number of active licenses use Microsoft Graph's cmd - Microsoft Q&A  by **Tyler Montney**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/661066/how-to-get-the-number-of-active-licenses-use-micro)